# IP based Google API key restriction problem

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using Google YouTube Data API v3 on a PHP based website and it works fine if there is no access restriction. APIs are called only from the server and not from client side.

However, if I setup a IP based restriction then all requests are blocked. It seems, that I set a wrong IP. I have already double checked the IP on my server and with ping as well and it is correct.

Any idea, what can be the problem?

Comment: did you add the internal ip or the external ip?   What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: Oh, silly me. This is on a shared server where my domain IP and server IP are different. Thanks for the tip!